# How to find the file at a certain btrfs inode

Tags: btrfs, inode

I have a corrupt file according to `btrfs`

```
BTRFS info (device sdb1): csum failed ino 367 off 310013952 csum 1601485211 expected csum 3692975992
```

I assumed ino 367 means inode 367, so I can use find and try to restore the file. However `find /path -inum 367` finds nothing. Anyone know how to find the corrupt file?

Comment: FWIW, find worked for me: `find /path -xdev -inum 367` turned up a file for three different inodes. My log messages are the same. Ubuntu 15.10, kernel 4.2.0.

Comment: Also look into `btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve`. I'll convert this into an answer if/when I become more confident about what I'm doing.

Comment: thanks @Reid  btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve does not list the filename. From irc chat on #btrfs it seems this may be a bug with older kernels

Answer (score 10):

Example:

```
sudo btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve 15380 /home
```

[`man btrfs-inspect-internal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/btrfs-inspect-internal.8.html) says:

```
   inode-resolve [-v] <ino> <path>
       (needs root privileges)

       resolve paths to all files with given inode number ino in a given
       subvolume at path, ie. all hardlinks

       Options

       -v
           verbose mode, print count of returned paths and ioctl()
           return value
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why find command didn't work for you. May be ino#367 deleted?
For me, both `find` and `btrfs-debug-tree` seems to be working fine.

```
$ find  /btrfs/ -inum 257
/btrfs/100kbfile.txt
$ ls -li /btrfs/100kbfile.txt 
257 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 102400 Nov 25 21:07 /btrfs/100kbfile.txt
```

You  can also try using 'btrfs-debug-tree' and grep for the objectid.

```
./btrfs-debug-tree  /btrfs/partition | grep -A2 257
```

find your inode/objectid from output. You can see the `name` associated
with objectid 257.

> location key (257 INODE_ITEM 0) type FILE
>
> namelen 13 datalen 0 name: 100kbfile.txt

Comment: Thanks, as stated this appears to be a bug in older kernels, 3,14 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The method "find /path -inum xxx" works with newer kernels, issue is a bug in older brtfs kernel code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the filenames of multiple inodes, here's a script based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/869356/322507).

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

usage() {
    printf "Usage: %s /filesytem inode(s)\n" "$(basename "$0")" 2>&1
}

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    usage; exit 1
fi

fs=$1
shift

if [[ ! -e $fs ]]; then
    usage; exit 1
fi

for i in "$@"; do
    # printf "%s " "$i"
    sudo btrfs inspect-internal inode-resolve "$fs" "$i"
done
```